# How to assign <s:property value="a"> value to a jsp variable

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Can anybody tell how to assign a value coming from "`<s:property value="a">"` into jsp variable ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the s:set tag for this.

For example this will call getA() from your action and put the value into "avalue", don't use **name** instead of **var**

```
<s:set var="avalue" value="a" />
```

And then you can reference it like so on the JSP:

```
<b>Print value defined in set tag :</b> <s:property value="#avalue" /> <br/>
```

Which will print out the value.

Comment: +1, but should be var instead of name for the set tag, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The struts property tag generates output not input.  If you want to do something else with the value that `s:property` would output, the equivalent code would be `getA()`, which is what `s:property` will use to get the value that it will print.

https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/property.html

Answer (score 1):

As Tim mentioned, `<s:property value="a"/>` is equivalent to calling the action's `getA()` method. You can get this using the JSP EL as `${action.a}`.

If you need to evaluate an OGNL expression and store that in an EL variable, you would probably need a custom tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following to get the value in to variable,

For example there is a string avalue,

`String avalue="";`

Now you can assign a property value to it by using,

```
<s:property value="a"/>
avalue=request.getAttribute("a");
```

above will gives the property value to a string variable. otherwise u can set the value and then assign it through getAttribute.

Comment: This is not correct; `a` is not a request attribute, but a value in the value stack.

Comment: ya, but its the value which i am getting from action controller and for which i have written setters and getters. in my project i am using the same its working fine for me

Comment: Hmm, perhaps the request wrapper is responsible for this, that would make sense. But why on earth would you *want* to access it like this?

Comment: hmm actually in that am getting some value like a=30. so by using this i want to iterate the loop to display from values from 1-30 ..