# assign a value from a jsp property to a java variable

Tags: java, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to assign <s:property value=“a”> value to a jsp variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440809/how-to-assign-sproperty-value-a-value-to-a-jsp-variable)

I trying to assign a value from a jsp property to a java variable but it doesn't seem to work for me...

here is the error: 
`An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/ fivepluscms/client/CMSGallery.jsp
Syntax error on token "=", ; expected.`

And here is the code:

```
<s:set var="data"></s:set>
<% int nume =%><s:property value="#data"/><%;%>
```

I mention that i have getters and setters in the action class for this variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how about this: `<s:set var="data" value="0"/>` ?

Answer (score 1):

`<s:set name="nume" value="data" />` will call `getData()` in your action class and assign the return value to the `nume` variable.